# Bottle and Json

Tags: python, json, bottle

How do I go about returning json data from a bottle request handler.  I see a dict2json method in the bottle src but I am not sure how to use it.

What is in the documentation:

```
@route('/spam')
def spam():
    return {'status':'online', 'servertime':time.time()}
```

Gives me this when I bring up the page:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>statusservertime</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I moved on to flask and it works fine.

Comment: You can also use import json then json.dumps(dict).  But good move, I also go between bottle and flask and end up choosing flask.  I like bottle being lightweight and not having a bigger framework behind it.  But stuff like typed url params always win me back for doing things like date detection or indexes i.e. /blog/<int:day>/<int:month>/<int:year>/<path:path>/  Where bottle only has :param names.  So a path with 4 slashes isn't always a date/blog type url. I use both but tend to flask for bigger apps currently due to stuff like this.

Comment: I have this problem too. When I use curl -I, I see that the content type is wrong: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Simply return a dict. Bottle handles the conversion to JSON for you.

> Even dictionaries are allowed. They are converted to json and returned with Content-Type header set to application/json. To disable this feature (and pass dicts to your middleware) you can set bottle.default_app().autojson to False.

```
@route('/api/status')
def api_status():
    return {'status':'online', 'servertime':time.time()}
```

Taken from [the documentation.](https://github.com/defnull/bottle.paws.de/blob/master/pages/docs.md#json)

http://bottlepy.org/docs/stable/api.html#the-bottle-class

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question

Answer (score 6):

For some reason, bottle's auto-json feature doesn't work for me. If it doesn't work for you either, you can use this decorator:

```
def json_result(f):
    def g(*a, **k):
        return json.dumps(f(*a, **k))
    return g
```

Also handy:

```
def mime(mime_type):
    def decorator(f):
        def g(*a, **k):
            response.content_type = mime_type
            return f(*a, **k)
        return g
    return decorator
```

Comment: This worked great for me to return arrays of dictionaries, which aren't handled by Bottle

Comment: You shouldn't be returning a list of dictionaries, which is why bottle makes it so difficult (and Flask as well). See here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/security/#json-security

Comment: Returning lists of dictionaries is good now. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/security/#json-security

Answer (score 3):

`return {'status':'online', 'servertime':time.time()}` works perfectly well for me. Have you imported `time`?

This works:

```
import time
from bottle import route, run

@route('/')
def index():
    return {'status':'online', 'servertime':time.time()}

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

Comment: That didn't work for me. I did import time. I guess it's a version-related change of behavior.

Answer (score 0):

try this should works as intended

```
from bson.json_util import dumps
from bottle import route, run
import time

@route('/')
def index():
     return {'status':'online', 'servertime':dumps(time.time()) }

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

Answer (score 0):

it is easy to get json using bottle's request module

```
from bottle import request

json_data = request.json # json_data is in the dictionary format
```